# Why might I be getting a: TypeError: updatePassword is not a function

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have a simple react app with an update profile page, using firebase for auth, and when I try to change the password, I'm getting this error:TypeError: updatePassword is not a function.

Here is my UpdateProfile.js

```
import React, { useRef, useState } from "react";
import { Form, Button, Card, Alert } from "react-bootstrap";
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";
import { Link, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

export default function UpdateProfile() {
  const emailRef = useRef();
  const passwordRef = useRef();
  const passwordConfirmRef = useRef();
  const { currentUser, updateEmail, updatePassword } = getAuth();
  const [error, setError] = useState("");
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  function handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (passwordRef.current.value !== passwordConfirmRef.current.value) {
      return setError("Passwords do not match");
    }

    const promises = [];
    setLoading(true);
    setError("");

    if (emailRef.current.value !== currentUser.email) {
      promises.push(updateEmail(emailRef.current.value));
    }
    if (passwordConfirmRef.current.value) {
      promises.push(updatePassword(passwordRef.current.value));
    }

    Promise.all(promises)
      .then(() => {
        navigate("/");
      })
      .catch(() => {
        setError("Failed to update account");
      })
      .finally(() => {
        setLoading(false);
      });
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Card>
        <Card.Body>
          <h2 className="text-center mb-4">Update Profile</h2>
          {error && <Alert variant="danger">{error}</Alert>}
          <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <Form.Group id="email">
              <Form.Label>Email</Form.Label>
              <Form.Control
                type="email"
                ref={emailRef}
                required
                defaultValue={currentUser.email}
              />
            </Form.Group>
            <Form.Group id="password" data-testid="pword">
              <Form.Label>Password</Form.Label>
              <Form.Control
                type="password"
                ref={passwordRef}
                placeholder="Leave blank to keep the same"
              />
            </Form.Group>
            <Form.Group id="password-confirm">
              <Form.Label>Password Confirmation</Form.Label>
              <Form.Control
                type="password"
                ref={passwordConfirmRef}
                placeholder="Leave blank to keep the same"
              />
            </Form.Group>
            <div className="w-100 mt-2">
              <Button disabled={loading} className="w-100" type="submit">
                Update
              </Button>
            </div>
          </Form>
        </Card.Body>
      </Card>
      <div className="w-100 text-center mt-2">
        <Link to="/">Cancel</Link>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

the Error points to line 30, which is here in stars:

```
 if (emailRef.current.value !== currentUser.email) {
      promises.push(updateEmail(emailRef.current.value));
    }
    if (passwordConfirmRef.current.value) {
      **promises.push(updatePassword(passwordRef.current.value));**
    }
```

Can anyone see what I have wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Seems like an issue related to Firebase. I'm not familiar with Firebase's JS library, but it seems like you're importing `updatePassword` from the wrong place? See https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#set_a_users_password

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `updateEmail` and `updatePassword` functions can be imported from Firebase Auth SDK and not the Auth instance. Try updating your import statements to:

```
import { updateEmail, updatePassword } from "firebase/auth"
```

Comment: Thanks! Also had to pass currentUser before password.ref.currentValue.